# Does BLOB data types in SQLite supports FULL-text search?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I am developing an Application using PHP and SQLite. And I create a my table's column with BLOB data types. I want to know that does BLOB data types in SQLite supports FULL-text search?

Comment: Are you referring to FTS3 / FTS4 extensions? Or a WHERE clause?

Comment: @peterchen Yes I am referring FTS3 extension with BLOB data type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_2), the type specified is parsed, but ignored:

*a datatype name may be optionally specified for each column. This is pure syntactic sugar, the supplied typenames are not used by FTS or the SQLite core for any purpose.*

This suggests that all columns in the table are created as TEXT or TEXT-like columns.

(As I understand, you are supposed to move columns eligible for full-text search to a separate virtual FTSx table, and just reference them through their FTSDx rowid).