# SQLite, text search FTS etc

Tags: sqlite, delphi, delphi-5, fts3, fts4

I am doing some updates and repairs on some old D5 business stuff (freebie for friend) with SQLite3 so have to use Zeos 6.6

I would like to speed up a text search which currently uses two BLOB_TEXT Fields, "Class" and "Methods"

```
if not(cbSearchMatchCase.Checked) then
  SearchText:=UpperCase(SearchText);
while not(dm.tbl.EOF) do
begin
  SearchData:=dm.tbl.FieldByName(fldClass).AsString+' '+
              dm.tbl.FieldByName(fldMethods).AsString;
  if not(cbSearchMatchCase.Checked) then
    SearchData:=UpperCase(SearchData);
  MatchFound:=AnsiPos(SearchText,SearchData) > 0;
  dm.tbl.Edit;
  dm.tbl.FieldByName(fldSearch).AsBoolean:=MatchFound;
  dm.tbl.Post;
  pbMain.StepIt;
  dm.tbl.Next;
end;
```

Can anyone point me at some code for using the SQLite FTS extension or something quicker than the above?

I found this but can't get it to work for way too many reasons to define here. I am sure it works as Žarko Gajić stuff is always spot-on, but just not working this installation. :)
http://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/full-text-txt- ... g-project/

Just find this link here...
[Does BLOB data types in SQLite supports FULL-text search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854487/does-blob-data-types-in-sqlite-supports-full-text-search)

That might explain why nothing seems to work, The BLOB_TEXT is being ignored? Yes? No?

Any snippets to speed this Text Search up?

Comment: One thing is not to loop over FieldByName. Declare a `TField := dm.tbl.FieldByName(fldClass)` outside the loop, use TField.AsString inside.

Comment: @JanDoggen Thanks, but that only shaved .8 of a second off 600 records in the test database and we have 20,000 in the real thing. Currently that is running the Search at 18-seconds per 1000. To make any impact I need to get FTS4 working.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to create index on class / method? It can be expression index: https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html or even complex one. I would start with lower case, and then re-filter if case sensitivity is needed.